# How to edit form in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Hi i have a form i used jquery to give a value to submit button, it is working fine.

```
jQuery('#frm_f_container.with_frm_style .submit input[type="submit"]').val('');
```

Now the form code is placed inside the wp super pop up pro. It is a pop up plugin it contains iframe when i inspect with firebug

The same jquery is not working so i tried `contents()` as suggested for iframe but this too not setting the button value here is the code i tried

```
jQuery('.sppro_cboxIframe').contents().find('#frm_f_container.with_frm_style .submit input[type="submit"]').val('');
```

Here `.sppro_cboxIframe` is the class placed with iframe like this

```
<iframe class="sppro_cboxIframe" frameborder="0" name="sppro_cbox1381566909072" src='url'>
```

when i view the source i can't able to see iframe like the above.

Now how to change or add values to the form inside it. Any help would be thankful.

Comment: [Same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)?

Comment: yes both are from same origin(site)

Comment: Your code looks fine, must be something else

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to manipulate elements inside the iframe from outside the iframe with javascript. See this answer regarding same origin policy:

[jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Check to see if that plugin allows you to pass in your jQuery into the iframe. That's the only way you'll get to manipulate the elements inside the iframe.

Comment: Thanks i tried giving this script in the plugin html editor.when i save i see the script are started with `<![CDATA[ `

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *jQuery* defined as `$` inside the `<iframe>`, passing [*same origin*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), and that the page inside the `<iframe>` has started loading, you can get the *Window* reference of an [*HTMLIFrameElement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement) via it's `contentWindow` property.

```
// get the <iframe> and then it's contentWindow
var iWin = document.getElementsByClassName('sppro_cboxIframe')[0].contentWindow;
// now to use jQuery inside <iframe>
iWin.$.find('#frm_f_container.with_frm_style .submit input[type="submit"]').val('');
```

Comment: `TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined`. When i view the source from the browser i can't find the iframe with this class.That is why the error coming.I don't know.Thanks for the help @Paul S

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T86yw/

```
jQuery('.sppro_cboxIframe').contents().find('#frm_f_container.with_frm_style .submit input[type="submit"]').val('New Value');
```

The issue is somewhere else. As you say both pages have the same origin, another thing to check is whether the iframe is already loaded when you run the code.

Comment: Thanks when i view the source ctrl+u i can't able to see this iframe code.Is that causing problem? @Christophe

Comment: Are you talking about my demo, or your page?

Comment: Am talking about my page

Comment: The source of the parent page won't show the iframe code. To see it you have to look at the source code of the iframe itself.